# How to add cells to UITableview inside UICollectionview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have got a collectionview
`class ChatLogController: UICollectionViewController`

and a tableview inside it

```
let colors: UITableView = {
    let div = UITableView();
    div.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.90, alpha: 1)
    return div;
}()
```

Now i want to add cells to colors table,where should i put the `numberOfSectionsInTableView` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add `datasource` and `delegate` to the `UITableView`. Some readings for you  [delegate](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableviewdelegate) and [datasource](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableviewdatasource).

So it should be.

```
div.datasource = self
div.delegate = self
```

And than in the class that is `datasource` and `delegate` for the `UITableView` add methods for rendering and filling cells with data.

Edited code example.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let colors: UITableView = {
        let div = UITableView();
        div.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.90, alpha: 1)
        return div;
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        colors.dataSource = self
    }
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource {

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 5
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 3
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier", for: indexPath)
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text="saksaokoask"
        cell.addSubview(label)
        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: `'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier reuseIdentifier - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'`

Comment: Yes you should register own cell for the custom table view. Read about how to work with table view please.

Comment: Благодарствую ибо вы мне очень помогли.

Comment: @BrunoSnickers пожалуйста